# can we get version notification for android app removed from from one account and uploaded it on another account with same package name?

Tags: android, version

I have to remove my app from one market account and have to upload this same app with higher version and same package name on another market account. So, can I get notification change of new version for this app which are already downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, no, you cannot...